# Wicked pdf: can I put my 2 page content in a single page?

Tags: css, pdf, ruby-on-rails-4, wicked-pdf

I'm converting my page contents using wicked pdf to PDF format. The contents are showing in the pdf in multiple pages. As my contents are dynamic, so I cannot check where the page break occurs and thus my pdf looks like a little bit odd. Can I show my contents in the pdf as an infinite page length? Is there any option available?

I've searched a bit in google, and found something like `page-break-after:always;` **CSS** property. But it doesn't help.